# PUblish android application to market - Individual developer

Tags: android, google-play

I have developed a android application which I want to publish to market. I have developed the app using Eclipse IDE I have gone through the publish related checklist and documents.

Here I have few doubts :

1. The certificate mentioned in the checklist, is it the same which I have used while exporting my app from Eclispe ?
2. I am a individual developer. Do I need to give the Company name ?
3. How much time it takes to activate once I publish the app ?

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Shankar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. (I am assuming you followed the instructions at http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)
2. You can give your name as the company name.
3. It is active immediately. :-) . There is no approval process or moderation.

Comment: let me know if this is too much of a hijack but I couldn't find a definitive answer:

If I publish an update will Android notify the user when they start my app or should I keep track of that myself in app and let the user know manually?

Comment: The Market app on the user's phone will notify them once in a while, about available updates to the app. If you are particular on users getting more immediate notification of updates, you will have to do it manually.

Comment: any idea of how long 'once in a while' is?

Comment: I think once in 2-3 days. Definitely at least once a week.

Comment: @sparkymat let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1821/discussion-between-alex-and-sparkymat)

Answer (score 0):

I have recently published my sms scheduler app "In Time SMS". During the final days I face 
same state as of you now. So, I think, I may can provide some answers to your questions.

For your queries:

1. It is the same certificate that you used during exporting app in eclipse. Save your   keystore elsewhere.
2. You do not need a company name. You can publish your app as individual.
3. Normally it takes 15min-2hrs depending upon the published version distribution in several
   servers of Google.

FYI:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.in.time.sms

http://intimesms.wix.com/reminder